# Can we change background image with CSS3 Animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

so I have this

```
<section id="indsection">
</section>

#indsection {
width: 1024px;
background-image: url(images/indexartbg1.png);
float: left;
height: 600px;
background-position: left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: rgba(51,51,51,.4);
border-right-color: rgba(51,51,51,.4);
border-bottom-color: rgba(51,51,51,.3);
border-left-color: rgba(51,51,51,.4);
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#indsection:hover {
background-color: rgba(153,0,51,.8);
}
```

This section is 1024px width, and 600px height. It has a background image "indexartbg1", which are some abstract lines in grey, and background of the image is transparent.
I want, when I hover over that section, that the section background color, turns from "none" to "red" (what color doesn't matter now). That I have done. At the same time I want that my background image "indexartbg1" gets replaced with "indexartbg2", which is basically the same picture, just instead of grey, it's colored in white. The point is, I want on hover that the new pictures kicks in (which is "white abstract lines") with the new background color. I think it would make a nice animation and combo. Anyone can help?!
Thank you.
Normal section state : http://pokit.org/get/?303fc63fc8f14aa4787f705cbf76bb10.jpg
Hover section state : http://pokit.org/get/?068b39e023b8d8beeed470a8ca9aae01.jpg

Comment: While I don't think that this is possible in CSS3 with background images, you might be able to play with Opacity and achieve a similar effect. [Take a gander at this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)

Comment: Actually I just added now to #indsection:hover the property of "Background-image: url(images/indexartbg2.png);" And it works. Need to check out now everything again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a smooth transition between the two states, you can use opacity and a pseudo element to display an other background-image and color on hover :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2NmMD/50/)**

*HTML :*

```
<section id="indsection"></section>
```

*CSS :*

```
#indsection {
    position:relative;
    width: 1024px;
    background-image: url(http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/237/2/9/indexartbg1_by_aortafx-d7wnc11.png);
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .4);
    border-right-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .4);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .3);
    border-left-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, .4);
}
#indsection:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(153, 0, 51, .8);
    background-image: url(http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/237/d/a/indexartbg2_by_aortafx-d7wnc0w.png);
    opacity:0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
#indsection:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: @ncubica css transitions are supported by IE10+ (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) for older browsers the change will be sudden without transition but won't crash.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2NmMD/48/ Here guys. I think I got it. I don't know if it's the right way?!

Comment: I think your right while dont use it before IE9. Cause IE8 dont have a proper support of pseudo elements (whitout using a polyfill of course)

Comment: @web-tiki Does my method (just adding Background-image: property works fine? I just tested in Chrome and it's not smooth enough (or i have pc problems)

Comment: @amirFX your technique works, the reason it is not smooth (only on first hover) is because the image for second is downloaded when you hover and it takes a little time. If you use the technique I describe in my answer, the image is downloaded before the hover state is called and therefore it displays straight away.

Comment: @web-tiki Yup. I just finished the changes. It is so smooth now. Thank you man. You're a saviour !!!!!